# PHP Not Loading Configurations from php.ini in Custom Location (Apache on Windows 8)

Tags: php, apache

I had a WAMP environment with php installed in `C:\SP\php`. Every thing worked fine.
I recently desired to place my php.ini file in a custom directory: `C:\SP\confs\`, and it didn't work.

Here are my `httpd.conf` directives:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/SP/confs/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/SP/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

In `C:/SP/confs/php.ini` I had this:

```
extension_dir = C:\SP\php\ext
date.timezone = Africa/Lagos
```

Errors appeared everywhere suggesting that many functions (e.g. mysql) were undefined.

The `phpinfo()` showed the following:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\windows

Loaded Configuration File: C:\SP\confs\php.ini

Extension_dir: C:\php

Default timezone: UTC (with warnings like: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings....)
```

My Server Software is : `Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11`

Now all this seems to suggest that my custom `php.ini` was found and loaded (according to phpinfo()) but somehow its directives were completely ignored in favour of some server defaults.

Now, how could this be?

Answer (score 1):

This is an usual and annoying bug when you install apache/php even on wamp packages: it won't set your extension_dir, and hell breaks loose

Here is your bug:

```
Extension_dir: C:\php
```

Seems to me it should be c:\SP\php\ext right? check if there isn't a duplicated extension_dir setting that is overriding yours

Get into your php.ini and correct the extension_dir, it have all sorts of bugs if you leave it blank (documentation says it **should** use the default ext/ folder ... it doesn't)

Comment: Thanks @Caio for your attention. Like it says in the question, I have in `php.ini` this: `extension_dir = C:\SP\php\ext`. There's no other overriding `extension_dir` directive. And even more strange, `phpinfo()` lists the `Loaded Configuration File` as `C:\SP\confs\php.ini` which is the very `php.ini` I'm working on! Also, note that not only `extension_dir`, but also `date.timezone` is ignored.

Comment: I needed to add that, for some reason, this directive: `error_log = C:\SP\php\php_errors.log` is working from the same `php.ini`, as error messages are properly appearing there.

Comment: well beats me, it seems the correct .ini is being loaded, but it is not accepting some configurations. Try changing the php.ini? If you move it to windows root folder, it will use it there. Other than that, no idea. I don't know how you installed apache/php, do you have administrative permission on all folders? can the process access those files?

Comment: I've found the culprit! In my `php.ini`, somewhere below the declaration of `error_log = C:\SP\php\php_errors.log`, I had a line that should have been `doc_root = `. But instead, it was just a hanging ` = `. I guess I had inadvertently deleted the "doc_root" part, resulting essentially in a syntax error. Strange that PHP could not flag the syntax error! Anyhow, thank you @Caio for sticking with me through this.

Comment: yeah, that breaks the parser, but usually that also fails PHP load and breaks Apache. At least on my installations if anything is wrong with any config file, Apache won't start, weird

Comment: I had extension_dir set to 'ext' and still had this issue with apache. I had to make it an absolute path for it to work